# How to query ansible dictionary with dynamic variables

Tags: variables, ansible

How do I query Ansible dictionary with dynamic variables?
I want to use ansible to read the serial number from the idrac of dell, and then set the address according to the serial number.
My source code:

```
---
- hosts: all
  name: set iDRAC Ipaddr
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    svctag_test: xxx30S2
    network_configs:
     xxx30S2:
       ip: 192.168.192.86

  tasks:

    - name: get dell server service-tag
      raw: racadm getsvctag
      register: svctag

    - name: show svctag
      debug: 
      msg="{{ svctag }}"      
     
    - name: show network 
      debug: 
        msg="{{ network_configs[svctag_test].ip }}"
    - name: set idrac ip svctag to vars
      set_fact:
        SVCTAG: "{{ svctag.stdout_lines }}" 
    - name: show SVCTAG
      debug: 
        msg="{{ SVCTAG }}"   
         
    - name: show network 2
      debug: 
         msg="{{ network_configs[SVCTAG].ip }}"
         #msg="{{ network_configs[SVCTAG] }}"   
         #msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][network_configs][SVCTAG] }}"
    
      #msg="{{ lookup('vars', network_configs )[SVCTAG]}}" 
     - name: set dell server idrac ip form service-tag
       raw: racadm config -g cfgLanNetworking -o cfgNicIpAddress "{{ network_configs[SVCTAG].ip }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- name: set idrac ip svctag to vars
  set_fact:
    SVCTAG: "{{ svctag.stdout_lines }}"
```

svctag.stdout_lines is a list, not a string. Try:

```
- name: set idrac ip svctag to vars
  set_fact:
    SVCTAG: "{{ svctag.stdout_lines[0] }}"
```